# Result of calculation (PHP)

Tags: php

For example somebody write on site into input 2+2 and then variable goes to php by GET. Php print variable as 2+2. How to automatically convert it to result of given calculation (4)?

Comment: You need to write code that parses it and performs the appropriate calculation. You could use `eval()`, but that opens up an enormous can of worms.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951373/when-is-eval-evil-in-php?s=1|0.0000 for why `eval()` is not a good idea.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Try to check the input field for existing + sign in the input value posted.

If yes then you can simply add the two numbers

Comment: Ok, thanks i didnt thought about this but what if there is more? Like 2*2+2.

Comment: Not really helpfull as this doesn't describe how to add both numbers in code, and I think OP has already figured out that numbers need to be added if one is using the plus symbol.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you want to rely on `eval` (I don't recommend it), or want to include/design code for recognizing arbitrary arithmetic operators or any combination of them (with or without but not limited to using parenthesis), I would recommend using a math parser such as https://github.com/mossadal/math-parser. You can install it using composer: https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md.

Comment: Okay i will check it later, thanks.